# How to archive a vertical-slider like in example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

does someone know how this effect is even called and how is it done?

already tried something like this - but it's buggy and not working properly like i want it to. also not really good in fullscreen mode. first two images are logo and a navigation

```
<div style="position:relative;height:720px;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/95x85" width="95" height="85" style="position:absolute;left:14px;top:27px;z-index:1000;" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x465" width="120" height="465" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:145px;z-index:1001;" />
  <div id="img1" style="width:1920px;height:1080px;background-image:url('https://unsplash.it/g/1920/1080?image=0');position:absolute;left:0px;"></div>
  <div id="img2" style="width:1920px;height:1080px;background-image:url('https://unsplash.it/1920/1080?image=0');position:absolute;left:0px;"></div>
  <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/273339-200.png" width="200" height="200" style="position:absolute;background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25); top: 50%;" id="border" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
  var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
  var border = document.getElementById('border');

  img1.onmousemove = redraw;
  img2.onmousemove = redraw;
  border.onmousemove = redraw;


  function redraw(e){
    posx = e.pageX - findPosX(img1);

    if (posx!=null&&posx>0&&posx<1600){
      img1.style.width=posx+"px";

      img2.style.backgroundPosition=(-posx)+"px";
      img2.style.left=posx+"px";
      img2.style.width=(1600-posx)+"px";

      border.style.left=(posx-100)+"px";
    }

  }


  function findPosX(obj){
  var curleft = 0;
  if(obj.offsetParent)
    while(1){
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      if(!obj.offsetParent)
        break;
      obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
  else if(obj.x)
    curleft += obj.x;
  return curleft;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y7nfzw6z/

the effect can be found here: http://www.e2save.com/if-only-it-was-4k/

i'll add a screenshot of the website so you can see which effect i mean.

[image]

Comment: yeh yeh.. edited, reopen please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dustin: It called Comparison Slider. There are a lot of good resource out there.

https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-jquery-image-comparison-slider/

https://medium.com/jotform-form-builder/making-a-responsive-image-comparison-slider-in-css-and-javascript-f3a691a9dd71#.d76grg41h

Comment: oh nice zurb has something out of the box in foundation. that sounds great.